# gnome-terminal: "--name" parameter only works for first window

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, i3

If I run

1. `gnome-terminal --name foo`
2. `xprop`

the window properties are correct:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "foo", "Gnome-terminal"
```

If I run this again with anoter name, e.g. `gnome-terminal --name bar`, `xprop` gives me for the second window again the same properties

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "foo", "Gnome-terminal"
```

Expected would be

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "bar", "Gnome-terminal"
```

Is this behavior intended or is it a bug?

(Background: I need to name the gnome-terminal windows to apply some individual commands in the i3 window manager.)

Comment: Gnome terminal daemonizes in first invocation. Perhaps that is the problem..